# cvtColor crashes on conversion

Tags: opencv, c++-cli

I load a frame from camera with external dll to my OpenCV program. I can see the frame  `cv::imshow("edges", frame);` and everything is ok. `frame.channels()` gives me 3 channels but when I try to `cv::cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);` application crashes.

```
CreateImage(System::Byte *imgData, int height, int width,int show)
{

    frame = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3, imgData);

    if (show > 0)
        cv::imshow("edges", frame); //I can see myself

    return frame.channels(); //three channels
}

void ConvertAndProcess()
{
    cv::Mat gray;

    cv::cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY); //crash...

    //do something
}
```

I've been digging for some time but no results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `imgData` is pinned?

Comment: @Qbul3kZ Are you able to imshow() just before cvtColor()?

Comment: The problem is in whatever calls CreateImage and ConvertAndProcess. More code is needed.

Comment: What do you mean by "crash...". Is there any exception information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

careful !

```
 frame = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3, imgData);
```

this is a 'borrowed' pointer. when imgData leaves scope (at the end of the function), frame.data is invalid.

that means, that you can't expect frame to be valid in ConvertAndProcess() if you constructed it this way.

you could clone() it, to achieve a 'deep copy':

```
 frame = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3, imgData).clone();
```

Comment: That was it. I didn't make a 'deep copy'. Thank's alot =)

Comment: This was it for me too! Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 2):

Check in `void ConvertAndProcess()` if the `frame` contains something or not. It seems like that the `frame` is empty and therefore there is nothing to convert from BGR to GRAY.

you can do the following:

```
if(!frame.empty())
    cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
else
{
    cout<<"\nFrame is empty.";
    return;
}
```

Comment: If frame.empty() is false, about the only other possibility is corrupted memory (which may result according to scenario raised by berak, if pixels in frame are modified)